# Update only a single key in a javascript object with map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions, map-function

I want to update my `thumbnail` key in my object.

```
products :[
 {
    id: 1,
    name: "sth,
    thumb : 'abc.jpg'
 }
];
```

I want to update the `products.thumb` of all the `objects` in that array like `thumb: 'server/abc.jpg`

```
searchedProducts = products.map(product => {
    return Object.assign({},
    product, 
    product.thumb = product.thumb ? 'server'+product.thumb : '')
});
```

**Current output**

```
[{
    0: 's,
    1: 'e',
    3: 'r',
    4: 'v',
    5: 'e',
    id: 1,
    thumb :'server/abc.jpg'
}]
```

Comment: If you don't care about changing the original object you can use `.forEach`

Comment: I will settle for that one too.. but you see trying to be a functional guy .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to use `Object.assign` like so:

```js
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'sth',
    thumb : 'abc.jpg'
  }
]

const searchedProducts = products.map(product => {
  return Object.assign({}, product, {
    thumb: product.thumb ? 'server/' + product.thumb : ''
  })
})

console.log(searchedProducts)
```

In the above snippet I'm merging:

- An empty object.
- With the currently iterated `product` object.
- With another object containing the computed `thumb` key.

Comment: Absolutely correct.. didnt know i had pass another argument about it .. why is that? .. the `thumb` passed later is actually `product.thumb`?

Comment: @ReyYoung What you did was roughly the equivalent of `Object.assign({}, 'string')`; assigning a string instead of assigning key/value pairs.

Answer (score 5):

With spread syntax:

```js
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'sth',
    thumb : 'abc.jpg'
  }
];

searchedProducts = products.map(product => {
  const thumb = product.thumb ? 'server/' + product.thumb : '';
  return { ...product, thumb };
});

console.log(searchedProducts);
```

Comment: I like this one :) Very clear what it is doing and no mutation

Answer (score 1):

Why would this not work for you?

```js
const products = [
 {
    id: 1,
    name: 'sth',
    thumb : 'abc.jpg'
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    name: 'sth',
    thumb : 'def.jpg'
 }

];

// Non mutating

let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
copy.forEach(product => {
    product.thumb = product.thumb ? 'copyserver/'+product.thumb : '';
});
console.log(copy);

// Mutating

products.forEach(product => {
    product.thumb = product.thumb ? 'server/'+product.thumb : '';
});
console.log(products);
```

Comment: Judging from the OP comments, I think the OP wants a more a functional approach.

Comment: This is correct and the most resourceful answer. None of the answers here offer the econmy of motion that forEach offers. It walks the array once and does not create new objects, which is pretty big deal.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I disagree; For one the OP stated he prefers not to mutate the original array, so statements like that are invalid in the context of this question. Also `map` walks the array once too.

Comment: @Nil Kyriakides, forEach is atleast twice as resourceful (it doesn't return too), not mutating the objects is cool and nice until your array size is >10000 and forEach becomes way more resource friendly. Solutions other than using plain forLoop, while or forEach is just not scalable. You can still opt for other solutions, but should consider the array size here, if it is small, its ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with `.map` to modify all `thumb` properties.

See working example below:

```js
const products = [{id:1,name:"sth",thumb:"abc.jpg"},{id:2,name:"byt",thumb:"def.jpg"},{id:3,name:"mth"}],

res = products.map(({thumb, ...others}) => ({...others, "thumb": thumb ? "server/" + thumb:''}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure and get the `thumb` property and keep the remaining properties in `rest`. This way you can keep the remaining properties as they are:

```js
const products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "sth",
    thumb: 'abc.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "sth2",
    thumb: 'def.jpg'
  }
];

const newProducts = products
                      .map(({thumb, ...rest}) => ({ thumb: thumb ? `server/${thumb}` : ``, ...rest }));
    
console.log(newProducts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using `reduce`, initialising your start with an empty array,

```
const result = products.reduce((prev, next) => {
  next.thumb = `server/${next.thumb}`;
  prev.push(next);
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Just another way of doing it other than `map`.

Comment: Why reduce. It is a misleading function since you are actually NOT reducing anything and are using a side effect.

Comment: You're right, since op wanted a more functional approach and most answers already show how map could be used, I wanted to show another functional way to do this, though it doesn't make sense here, this was just meant as a something you could use in a more complex situation where you want to filter data inside map etc, then one reduce can replace those. Something for op to keep in his backpocket kind of answer. :)